# VPN/WIreguard forward traffic internally as well as externally

Tags: iptables, wireguard

This may be more of a Linux firewall question, but the context is the Wireguard VPN setup on Ubuntu. Note, I'm barely getting acquainted with a lot of this stuff.

I have Wireguard up and running on Digital Ocean Ubuntu with Windows and Android clients using it. All seems good.

The basic firewall commands I use when it comes up is/are below: So, the 3rd line appears to route all traffic coming in on `wg0` (private VPN) out through the public `eth0` interface. As it should (almost?) and it works fine. Wgo/Private network is `10.8.0.1/24` and the server is `10.8.0.1`. When a client traffic comes into the server below destined for `10.8.0.x` (another address within the private network) it times out.

I "thought" it is because it is attempting to route it through `eth0`? If so, how do I ensure that traffic destined for the private subnet remains using `wg0` interface? If not, any other suggestions?

```
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
PreUp = sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PostUp = iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostUp = ip6tables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ufw route delete allow in on wg0 out on eth0
PreDown = iptables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PreDown = ip6tables -t nat -D POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=0
PostDown = sysctl -w net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your default policy is to drop or deny forwarding in iptables/ufw. Then you are most likely missing the firewall/ufw entries for allowing the traffic to flow between the different wireguard interface(s) or in and out on the same interface.

You could check your dmesg for `[UFW BLOCK]` messages.

To allow unrestricted flow in and out on the same wg interface
`PostUp = ufw route allow in on wg0 out on wg0`

I prefer to modify the config file directly `sudo vim /etc/ufw/before.rules`
Go to filter, after the end of the required lines you can add the forwarding rules you need. Eg:

`-A ufw-before-forward -i wg0 -s 10.8.0.1/24 -o wg0 -d 10.8.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT`

This will allow traffic from(-s flag) 10.8.0.1/24 on interface wg0 to(-d flag) 10.8.0.1/24 on interface wg0. -i is the input interface and -o is the output interface.

If you prefer to use your up\down way, you can add iptables in front of the command.

`iptables -A ufw-before-forward -i wg0 -s 10.8.0.1/24 -o wg0 -d 10.8.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT`

Good luck :)

Comment: Just got back to this.  As suggested i added
iptables -A ufw-before-forward -i wg0 -s 10.8.0.1/24 -o wg0 -d 10.8.0.1/24 -j ACCEPT

but to my wg0.conf file as, indeed this is exactly what i wanted.  traffic within that subnet to stay on wg0.  It appears to have worked perfectly, thanks !!
I'm not familiar with the before.rules configuration file,  so stuck with wg0.conf